# Pass Red function pointer to C

Tags: red, red-system

I know how to pass a `Red/System` callback to a C function, but is the same functionality possible to achieve with `Red`? It is possible to create a `Red/System` wrapper for a `Red` function *at runtime* and pass it to a C function?

I've already looked at a lot of bindings/code [here](https://github.com/red/code) and [there](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/runtime/datatypes/function.reds), but haven't found anything that solves my problem.

**Edit:**
Let's say that I've got a simple `Red` function:

```
add-numbers: func[a b][a + b]
```

and I have a `Red/System` function alias:

```
callback!: alias function! [a [integer!] b [integer!] return: [integer!]]
```

Is it possible to somehow convert the above `add-numbers` function to a `callback!` using a `Red/System` wrapper?

Comment: When asking questions, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke a Red `function!` from Red/System using the [#call](http://static.red-lang.org/red-system-specs-light.html#section-16.8) directive. Only simple argument types are auto-converted for you (like numbers and logic value), for the rest, you need to use the Red runtime API to construct and place the function's arguments on the Red stack, and to eventually retrieve the returned value.

Using `#call`, you can write wrapper functions in Red/System that can be passed as callbacks to C functions. Here is [an example](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/libRed/libRed.red#L1227) of such wrapper from LibRed's source code.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Which values exactly are auto-converted? Only `number!` and `logic!`?

Comment: `integer!`, `float!` and `logic!`. Other datatypes have no corresponding counterparts between Red and Red/System, so cannot be auto-converted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Red function at runtime and pass it to a C function - (without using Red/System), like this:

```
#include "red.h"

int main() {

    redOpen();

    // redDo("add-numbers: func[a b][a + b]"); // will not work
    redSet(redSymbol("add-numbers"), redDo("func [a b][a + b]"));
    redPrint(redCall(redWord("add-numbers"), redInteger(2), redInteger(3)));

    redClose();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cannot use any C code in my Project.